# Examples Of Planar Isometries of 3D surfaces

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces, isometry

Are there any interesting examples of planar isometries? I mean apart from some standard ones like: the Swiss-Roll and the S-curve which are isometric to a rectangular strip. Another one I guess would be a sector of a planar circle which is isometric to a cone in 3D. I am looking for any other interesting examples and the corresponding parametric formulas for such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tangent developables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_developable): union
of the tangents to a space curve.

Also, one can join developable surfaces together:

---

[image: fork]

          

<sup>Developable fork: [thegeometryofbending](http://thegeometryofbending.blogspot.com/2009/11/developable-fork.html).</sup>

---

Comment: Nice Suggestion, Thanks!